# Order by subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, sql-order-by

I have the following oracle SQL code, but I can't understand what is the purpose of ordering by a subquery. Anyone can explain it clearly to me ?

```
SELECT employee_id, last_name
  FROM employees e
 ORDER BY (
            SELECT department_name
            FROM departments d
            WHERE e.department_id = d.department_id
           );
```

Comment: The employees should ordered by their departments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ordering is done by results from other table. In this case the query returns only results from `employees` table, but the ordering is done by `department_name`, which is stored in `departments` table.

You could achieve identical result by using join, selecting only values from `employees` table, and ordering by `department_name` from departments table:

```
SELECT e.employee_id, e.last_name
FROM employees e INNER JOIN departments d
    ON e.department_id = d.department_id
ORDER BY d.department_name
```

This query is valid if employee must always have a department. If there can be employees without departments then you should use `LEFT` join instead.

Comment: This query relies on all values in the employees.department_id column existing in the departments.department_id column. Using a left outer join instead of the inner join would mean you guaranteed both queries always returning the same data. It would also be guaranteed if employees.department_id was a not null column, and was foreign keyed to departments.department_id.

Comment: @stevegodfrey That's a very good point, thank you. I added note at the end of the answer about the limitations of this query

Answer (score 1):

The clear intention of that query is employee_id and last_name from employees should be order by department_name from departments.

Okay, you don't subquery then go for join

```
select e.employee_id,e.last_name from employees e join departments d on
e.department_id = d.department_id order by d.department_name;
```